What does "free" mean in "free logic"?
An anonymous person and I are debating how we should translate "free logic" into Korean. They suggested "자유 논리(自由論理)" and I suggested "빈 논리(빈論理)." The noun "논리(論理)" means "logic."
The noun "자유(自由)" means "freedom." Since the word is used as an adnominal phrase in "자유 논리," its meaning here is "free," as in "free speech." According to them, free logic is free in the sense that it is free from the metaphysical requirement that each singular term should denote an object in the domain of quantification.
On the other hand, "빈," the adnominal form of the verb "비다," means "empty." So, "빈 논리" means "empty logic." I think free logic is free in the sense that its singular terms can be empty, that is to say, free.
I'm a native Korean, so it is difficult for me to figure out the exact meaning of "free" in "free logic." What does the word "free" mean here?

The definition of free logic in https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-free/#1.1 states "Free logic is formal logic whose quantifiers are interpreted in the usual way—that is, objectually over a specified domain D—but whose singular terms may denote objects outside of D, or not denote at all." – That’s exactly what you propose. Hence “free” in the above sense means "unrestricted".

Free logic is a logic with fewer existential presuppositions than classical logic. Thus "free of existential presuppositions".

Someone told me the Chinese Wikipedia uses "自由逻辑" for "free logic."

That is true tho 自由 is misleading. Empty is better imo

Since the Chinese term is "自由逻辑", as you observed, I think you would not go wrong with "자유 논리". Personally, I would prefer a direct translation of "unrestricted logic". Anyway the point is just that the current standard FOL is exactly equivalent to free logic plus the axiom ∃x ( x = x ). So it is not as free/unrestricted.

In case you are unaware, free logic is also equivalent to many-sorted FOL (where the sorts may be empty).
